# How to execute hub methods on database changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr

I'm using Entity Framework Core and SQLite as relational database, but also ASP.NET Core to display the data on a website.

Now what I want to do is every time something happens to the database (insert, update, delete), I also want a SignalR method to be executed. This way every client gets noticed about the changes.

Is it possible to observe the SQLite database?

Or should I call the hub methods manually after every statement to the db?

My Hub Class

```
public class GeneralHub : Hub
{
    public async Task ServerSendUpdate()
    {
        List<int> list = CountTickets();
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ClientReceiveUpdate", list);
    }

    private List<int> CountTickets()
    {
        NamedRestClient _namedRestClient = new NamedRestClient();
        return _namedRestClient.CountTickets().Result;
    }
}
```

At the moment the amount of objects in my database is displayed on the website by invoking method ServerSendUpdate()